# Salt / Hash in PHP vs in Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, security

Is there an advantage as to where password hash and salt occurs, in PHP vs in a database?  It seems having the process occur inside of a database would be the optimal solution; since the web server and the database would only have to exchange the password and not the salt.

Comment: Passwords are sensitive. Salts are not, and exist solely to mitigate viability of [rainbow table attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table).

Comment: Do you happen have a password-based key derivation function built into your database?

Comment: @llnk I don't see how this is a duplicate of the other question.  The other question deals exclusively with which hashing method is best, not with where the hashing occurs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's okay to store the salt in the database.  It's an advantage to do so, because you want to use a *different* random salt per user.

I recommend doing the hashing in the application.

The reason is that if you do the hashing in an SQL expression, and you use query logging on the database server, you might be storing plaintext samples of the user passwords in the query log.

Comment: +1 for the passwords stored in log issue

Answer (score 0):

If you're using something better than a simple hash + salt, like [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2), you're going to have to [involve PHP at this point](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php) AFAIK. So in terms of best location, for me, the best location is in the code because that's where you can do the "best" method of password hashing.